# How to erase data from Macintosh HD - Data - Data?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I just realised that there're over 400gb usage of data and I think there's that much data in my computer.
I need to an upgrade and I want to erase that from my Mac.
But I Cann't. Does anyone know how to?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it
First, go to terminal identify the disk that you want to delete with

```
diskutil list
```

and then
unmount(in this case delete) with this command

```
disktutil unmountDisk force (you disk dir you want to delete)
```

Comment: This indicates you didn’t get booted to recovery correctly. So glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Apple shows how to completely erase the disk here.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496

You have to boot to internet recovery since the system can’t erase itself while running, but you can sometimes script a reboot that then performs the erase...

- https://github.com/grahampugh/erase-install

Or connect to a different Mac over target disk mode (or even a PC could format the disk and you would need internet recovery or external installer to reinstall the OS).

Comment: I am wondering why can't I erase that disk.

Comment: If you follow the instructions precisely, it’s hardware failure. I, not going to say you aren’t following the instructions correctly, but at work less than 10% of the people that report they followed them did not. Most of the time it’s not clicking buttons in the correct sequence and place, but you need a technician to repeat the process or fix the drive. @mr.mr.soysauce